Jenkins - Docker cloud agent VS Docker in Pipeline
I'm trying to understand why so many people have taken the route of setting up "Docker cloud agent" (tutorial1, tutorial2) inside Manage Jenkins -> Clouds, instead of just going with "Docker agent" inside pipeline, which is officially supported (official documentation).
In my view, if I go with "Docker cloud agent" way,

I have to login to the server where Jenkins is hosted.
I need to edit Docker's service file "/lib/systemd/system/docker.service" and expose REST API port manually.
Do the setup in Manage Jenkins Cloud.
Create a Docker image of your own.
Add that Docker image under "Docker agent template"
Then finally refer that template's name in the pipeline.

UPDATE:

Found one more disadvantage. We should always use the base image from "jenkins/agent" OR its variants (jenkins/agent:alpine:jdk11) and then on top of it, we need to install all the required libraries OR Software.

Instead of all these extra steps, if I go with "Docker agent" support inside pipeline directly (official documentation),

I don't even need to login to server where Jenkins is hosted.
I can also do more customization using "Dockerfile" and committing it to the source code.

What is the exact reason for choosing OR when should I choose "Docker cloud agent"?
And where is the official documentation to expose Jenkins REST API port like this?
Thank you.

Setting up a jenkins agent is about as much effort as setting up a docker cloud agent when you have everything streamlined.

Well, the example tutorials you've linked seem to only illustrate the capabilities. No one exposes the Docker service port on the controller host in real life (also, using a freestyle job is from the pre-historical times). Instead, with an addition of Kubernetes plugin, Jenkins could be connected to the APIs of K8s clusters so that it can create build pods based on the templates defined in the pipelines. Also, both of the options support CasC. Both have their pros and cons. I'm not sure this question could be answered without being marked as opinion-based.

@Iterokun, I didn't get what exactly you mean. Everything streamlined means?

@AlexanderPletnev, regarding exposing controller host, that's what I also thought. with Jenkins, no one should be doing such file edits when everything is available in the Pipeline is what my argument is. Moreover, I couldn't find any such official documentation to do these things. But I asked this question here because, one of my senior is insisting to follow Docker cloud agent method without properly explaining me why.

I don't know if I can give a comprehensive answer to this question, but there is one aspect that comes to mind - jobs isolation. When you are using docker-plugin (that provides Docker cloud) Jenkins creates a new agent for each job run. When you are using docker symbol in agent at the stage level you are reusing pipeline level agents, and when you are doing it at the pipeline level your containers are running on the controller, which is not scalable.
Generally speaking, single use agents are more deterministic and secure, so you will end up using them, and docker-cloud is probably the easiest way to do it. Not the best way for sure, as @alexander-pletnev mentioned k8s is probably more flexible.

Hello Iterkun, Thank you for the reply. However I would like to get more clarification on your answer.  When you say "your containers are running on the controller" and in the second part, you have mentioned about using K8s as @alexander-pletnev mentioned. So you are referring all these when the Docker and the containers are being run on totally different system/server on the cloud right? But if the Docker is being run on the same OS where Jenkins is being run, then using Docker cloud agents doesn't make much sense. Am I right?

Arguably, it makes even more sense to properly isolate your agents if they are running on the same OS as Jenkins controller. Unless you can somehow enforce every job using pipeline { agent { docker you are exposing all the secrets you have configured in Jenkins. You allow jobs to change a lot of things on the OS that might affect other jobs.
